# How to use the conditional homepage tag

Tags: conditional-tags, headers, videos

I'm trying to display a video in the header of the homepage only but struggling to figure out the correct code. This is the code for the video tag, which seems to be working fine

```
if ( is_home() ) { ?> <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls preload="auto" width="1278" height="720"
poster="https://imagestocksg.s3.amazonaws.com/preview/homepage-poster-test.jpg"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="https://imagestocksg.s3.amazonaws.com/preview/homepage-video-test.mp4" 
type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<?php }
```

How do I use the conditional if ( is_home() tag to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

The blog posts index and site front page have been treated as two different query contexts, with `is_home()` applying to the blog posts index, and `is_front_page()` applying to the site front page.

Be careful not to confuse the two query conditionals:

On the site front page, `is_front_page()` will always return TRUE, regardless of whether the site front page displays the blog posts index or a static page.

On the blog posts index, `is_home()` will always return TRUE, regardless of whether the blog posts index is displayed on the site front page or a separate page.

If you are targeting Your site's home page, its recommended that you use :

```
 if( is_front_page() ){
   #all your stuffs here specific to home page
 }
```

have a look over [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to learn more.